# activate an automatically archived chatter group(because of inactivity of 90days)by apex code

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-groups

Can you activate a chatter group which has been archived for inactivity by apex code?
If so what are the permissions required to do this?
Is it that only owner of group/modify all data users can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ConnectApi functionality supports this.

```
...need some code to retrieve group id and optionally community id...
ConnectApi.Chatter​​GroupInput groupInput = new ConnectApi.Chatter​​GroupInput();
groupInput.isArchived = false;

ConnectApi.ChatterGroups.updateGroup(communityId, groupId, groupInput);
```

This example is almost identical to the example shown in the [Apex Code developer guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterGroups_updateGroup.htm) for the `ConnectApi.ChatterGroups.updateGroup()` method.

The downside to ConnectApi, however is that you only get access to the Chatter functionality according to the access of the context user. So if this were done by a trigger, say, and the user invoking it did not have manager access to the group, it would fail. The advantage is this update to the group lives outside of the normal Apex governor limits and is instead governed by the ConnectApi limits, which are typically a bit more generous.

If you need access no matter what, you would query for the chatter group needed, retrieve it, then update the group. The short version of this would look like this:

```
CollaborationGroup cg = [select Id from CollaborationGroup where Id = : someGroupId];
cg.IsArchived = false; 
update cg;
```

To be certain this would work no matter from where, you would want to then declare the class as `without sharing` ignoring sharing restrictions and ensuring any Apex invoked from anywhere else would successfully execute this code.

Comment: Hi peter this did work.but i came across somethings strange. for stimulating testcondition i had 100 chattegroup associated to me(by dataloader).when i tried to write testclass,i inserted a test record by code(this record internally creates a chattergroup) and it my test class gave me the expected error(which i had handled in code).So my question is how come testclasses could see chattergroup in org?i had specified seealldata = false

Comment: Interesting...I've not played with it, but that may be one of the object types that is always visible.

Comment: sfdc99999 I'd suggest a new question on visibility of CollaborationGroup under test conditions. It's worth investigating further than in the comments of this question/answer. Thx!